# Quadratic function question

Tags: quadratic-forms

Find an equation of the quadratic function whose f has zeros -1 and 3 and a maximum value of 8.

I've tried to use intercept form, but I'm not sure wha to do with the maximum value of 8.

Comment: another word for maximum can be vertice - does that help?

Comment: try forming your equation this way: $f(x) = - a (x - c) ^ 2 + 8$

Answer (score 1):

Since the function is quadratic and has zeroes at -1 and 3, it must have the form $$f(x) = c(x+1)(x-3)$$ for some constant  $c$.  Can you take it from there?